# HTML/ CSS: how to collapse targeting data by default

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

referring to the code below, the targeting data - **data-target="#navbar-ex1-collapse"** - should be collapsed by default because I have set the **data-toggle to collapse**  and only shows when button is clicked and disappears when button clicked again. But somehow the targeting data is shown by default and disappears when button is clicked.

My question is how can I make the targeting data collapsed by default? Many thanks!

#### By the way, I am using bootstrap.

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"><img src="images/hemorrhoid-logo-Horizontal.png.webp" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="nav navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Get Relief</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Ingredients</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hemorrhoid Types</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end of Collect the nav 1-->
```

Comment: where is your css?? And what do you mean by targeting data??

Comment: Hi @spirit I have updated my question.

Comment: Where is your css? Are you using javascript? Or is it any framework that you are using. We can't help unless you show us your code.

Comment: @spirit this is bootstrap im assuming by the markup, the css is included

Comment: @spirit I am using bootstrap.

Comment: @spirit this problem is solved. I added collapse class to my targeting data div. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the collapse class to the

```
<div class="nav navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex1-collapse">
```

So it should be

```
<div class="nav navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-ex1-collapse">
```

Here is a working example

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"><img src="images/hemorrhoid-logo-Horizontal.png.webp" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="nav navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Get Relief</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Ingredients</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hemorrhoid Types</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end of Collect the nav 1-->
</nav>
```

Comment: That is what I just did before you posted your answer. See my last response to @spirit. Thank you anyway.